# How to Remove Arrays and Apply formula into Each Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been using this formula since couple of days where it helps me alot to find the extact match from the raw data.

Earlier it was giving me an error `#Value and !` so i used `Substitue` Function to remove these error. I need to fix this problem as well so i can remove subsctitute

I am basically looking to to apply this fomrula on each cell separalty rather than `Array` i tried but it was not working when i removed the arrays.

I have raw data from which i copy paste the relvant data into cells manually where `Arrays` disturb them.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(UPPER(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(SPLIT(LOWER(B2:B), " "),""), LOWER("^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, 'Key words'!C1:C500)&"$")),""))),,999^99))),"#VALUE",""),"!",""))
```

If there is another `Exact Match Function` then please share. I would appreciate your help.

I hope to get some help. Thanks.

[Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OGxxI1jg82Rou0iAfRLrkezQFVXERB8X2VoD5go9ytI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: where did you get the arrayformula?

Comment: From the StackOverflow while searching

Comment: If you could provide a sample sheet and show what the formula does,  that would be easier for us to understand your formula.

Comment: Can you link to the discussion/post where you found it?  Either way, to get a formula working you'll probably have to share a sample of the sheet or better illustration of the problem, as opposed to just the old formula that isn't working.

Comment: Sure let me share an example worksheet

Comment: Updated the sheet link

Comment: seems like helping marketing for VirtualAssistant

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MKsW.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either in `C3` then just drag down:

#### JOIN:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(JOIN("", IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(LOWER(B3), " "), LOWER("^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, 'Match Criteria'!$B$2:$B)&"$")), ""))))
```

#### TEXTJOIN:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(LOWER(B3), " "), LOWER("^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, 'Match Criteria'!$B$2:$B)&"$")), ""))))
```

This will only return 1 cell due to `JOIN`/`TEXTJOIN` after `UPPER` so it won't write into the whole column thus allowing you to manually enter data in the column without disturbing the other values.

#### Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

use in C2:

```
={"State"; INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(B3:B, ", ", 1)&"", 
 QUERY("×|^"&'Match Criteria'!B2:B100&"$|×",,9^9)))),,9^9))))}
```

use in D2:

```
={"Zip Code"; INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C3:C, 
 {'Match Criteria'!B2:B, 'Match Criteria'!A2:A}, 2, 0)))}
```

[image]